# Quero fazer um botão que altere o background da página. Escrevi em js mas não sei porque não funciona

Tags: javascript

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ABC</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function changebgtoblue(){
                document.getElementById('bla').style.background-color="blue";
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            #bblue{
                background-color:blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body id="bla" /*style="background-color:#000;"*/>
            <button id="bblue" onclick="changebgtoblue()">blue</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

3 coisas erradas no teu código:

- Em HTML não podes comentar atributos, remove esse `/*` `*/`
- A propriedade `background-color` em JavaScript não pode ter `-`, tem de ser escrito em *camelCase*, ou seja: `backgroundColor`
- coloca o script no final do `body`, ou usa `onload` para correr o script. O teu código JavaScript ainda não sabe da presença do código HTML pois ele ainda não foi lido.

Exemplo corrigido:

```css
#bblue {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body id="bla">
  <button id="bblue" onclick="changebgtoblue()">blue</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function changebgtoblue() {
      document.getElementById('bla').style.backgroundColor = "darkblue";
    }
  </script>
</body>
```